# Android service closes after 10 seconds

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

I'm developing an Android App that tracks a few things in the background while the App is running. I'm kind of a beginner in Android, so i will try to describe what i want to do.

The setup:
MainActivity, TrackerActivity, TrackerService (The service contains a wakelock) and TrackerServiceWakeupReciever

This runs when the TrackerService is closes.

```
public class TrackerServiceWakeupReciever  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(); 
        serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.android.TrackerService");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("action", "checkSound");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

The code that starts the Service from TrackerActivity:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.android.TrackerService");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

When entering the App the MainActivity is starting, then when the TrackerActivity gets started from the MainActivity the TrackerService gets started in the onCreate of TrackerActivity. The service runs exactly 10 seconds an closes. Then the TrackerServiceWakeupReciever is starting the Service again and it run 10 second a again and loops.

Why does it only run in 10 seconds? I have noticed that if I quickly turn back to the MainActivity and press the sleep button then the service will keep running. Even when the device turns out of the sleep the service is running, as I want it to do.

How to solve this problem? Have used a week to figure it out. I guess it's simpel :)

Thanks in advance.
Martin

Comment: Do u want ur service to stay longer or say for a time u want?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of a non-processed implementation of goAsync() somewhere in one of your (other) BroadcastReceivers? After 10 seconds they shut down if you haven't called finish() on the PendingResult retrieved from goAsync(). See docs here:

[BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync%28%29)

Otherwise maybe (generally speaking) you block something for too long.